# How do I get CR3 files to show thumbnails on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: photo-management, photography

I am a new-ish Linux user who currently uses an R6 as my main camera and Darktable as my main photo editing software. My file manager shows thumbnails for my old .cr2 and .orf photos perfectly fine, and Darktable will edit .cr3 files perfectly normally, but they won't thumbnail in my file manager. This isn't a huge problem, but it would be nice to be able to cull down my photos without having to open darktable. I've found a few other people post online about this problem, but as far as I can tell no one else has posted about finding a solution.

I'm using Ubuntu with Nemo as my file manager, but Nautilus is of no help either. I've added a mime xml entry for it and updated the mime database, but that hasn't made any difference. I don't really know enough about Linux to know where the problem would even be here, so I don't know how much more progress I can really make.

exiv2 is fully updated to 0.27.5, and I do have bmff support enabled.

How do I get CR3 files to show thumbnails on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Comment: I'm using 22.04.2 LTS, I just downloaded it from the Ubuntu website. I was using Linux Mint and had the exact same problem.

Comment: Just FYI:  But I added the details *hidden away in your title* to your question text.. Not everyone uses large modern browsers on large screens; thus the title may not be visible when reading your question... The question text should be complete (*thus my edit*)